# $.getJSON got a response but console.log won't type it out

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I use the following jQuery to fetch some JSON from a x-server:

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON("/json.php?method=getStupid&jsoncallback=?",
        function(json){
            console.log('Success: ' + json);
        }
    );
});
```

The console is empty in every browser, but when I check the networks tab it all seem to work perfectly fine.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 04 Feb 2013 14:14:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze9
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 33
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

And this is what the response looks like:

```
({"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5})
```

It feels like everything within the function(json) { } is getting ignored. Is it a typo?

Comment: `({"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5})` isn't valid JSON. How do you build this ?

Comment: Why do you have jsoncallback=? in your url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending `jsoncallback=?`, which means you are requesting JSONP.  This is *only* used for cross-domain communication.  If this URL is on your domain, then just use JSON.

Lose the `jsoncallback=?`, and the `()` around the JSON in the response.  Then it will be valid JSON.

If you need to use JSONP, you need to format the request correctly.

First, JSONP is *not* JSON. It's actually a script tag being appended to the page. So, its `Content-type` should be `text/javascript`.

Second, the `jsoncallback` parameter is important. When sending back a response, you need to "wrap" the data in the value of that param.

So, if the request was `/json.php?method=getStupid&jsoncallback=test123`, the response should be:

```
test123({"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5})
```

Comment: Seems to work better, but I'm not sure how to handle the data. the GET is marked with red color in the console too (not sure what that means). http://jsfiddle.net/Bs5bF/2/

Comment: @estrar: `test123` was just an example, you aren't actually supposed to put a value there.  You just use `http://getwebinspiration.com/json.php?method=getStupid?jsoncallback=?`.  jQuery will fill in the `?` for you.  jQuery will send a value as the `jsoncallback` parameter for you, and you just need to wrap the data in the value of that parameter (whatever it is).

Comment: Ah, I feel a bit stupid now. This is my response now: /json.php?method=getStupid?jsoncallback=jQuery18309086269516609894_1359991673362&_=1359991673477

Now I just need to extract it somehow.

Comment: @estrar: Just get the value of the GET paramter!  `$_GET['jsoncallback']`.

Comment: It worked perfectly fine when I removed dataType : "jsonp". Seems like a silent error occours with it.

Answer (score 4):

As you have `jsoncallback=?` in your URL, the server is answering with JSONP.

The server is trying to build

```
functionName({"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5})
```

and as `getJSON` doesn't give a function name, you end with

```
({"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5})
```

which isn't JSON.

You can probably fix your problem by removing `jsoncallback=?` from the URL.

If the server can only answer in JSONP (which I doubt), then you'd better use the generic [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function.